# Google Images redirect Tampermonkey Script

Tags: firefox, tampermonkey, google-image-search, greasemonkey-4

Some days now google uses a new way to display image results, it adds among things a mosaic at the end of the URL, I use the Google Images Restored add-on on Firefox that displays the results like before August 6 2019, when I am logged out it works perfectly when I log in it uses the new way

Here are the example URLS searching "example":

Logged-Out: https://www.google.com/search?q=example&tbm=isch

Logged-In: https://www.google.com/search?q=example&udm=2#vhid=Jh5kTkUIdFpyAM&vssid=mosaic

Now how can I create a script to redirect the second URL to look like the first so that the add-on works?

I use Firefox 86.0.1

I have deleted the cookies and tried it to Firefox Portable 123.0 as well, there if you are logged-in it doesn't matter if you redirect it, it goes either way to the new mosaic style, if you are logged-out the add-on still works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.